# Difference between passing: method that returns a widget, a unique widget class, or a Widget object

Tags: flutter, widget, state

I am confused between these three ways of passing/building widgets:

1.

```dart
  Widget _myDisplay() {
    return [widgets showing content];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _myDisplay();
  }
```

2. 

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyDisplay();
  }
```

where `MyDisplay` is defined as such (I'm not sure if it's crucial whether `MyDisplay` is a `StatelessWidget` or a `StatefulWidget`):

```dart
class MyDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDisplay({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return [widgets showing content];
  }
}
```

3. 

```dart
  Widget _myDisplay = [widgets showing content];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _myDisplay;
  }
```

I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67900165/what-is-the-difference-between-passing-a-widget-class-and-simply-passing-a-funct) comparing the first two methods, and from what I understand, using a unique, named class extending `StatelessWidget` or `StatefulWidget` allows you to use the `const` keyword which signifies that it will not be rebuilt when the Widget tree is rebuilt.

However, what about the 3rd method above? Is it the same as 1. or 2., or completely different? If so, how is it different and when is it preferred?

Thanks!

Comment: Also see [What is the difference between functions and classes to create reusable widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53234825/)

Answer (score 0):

- Type 1: helper methods
- Type 2: Widgets
- Type 3: Variables

For type 1 and 2, I will highly recommend to check [Widgets vs helper methods | Decoding Flutter](https://youtu.be/IOyq-eTRhvo)

Helper methods will rebuild everything on every state changes which can be heavy based on scenario like using animated-widgets.

Try using Widget with `const` constructor to get better performance,

Now for the 3rd type variable. It is totally different from helper method and widgets. This variable won't change until you handle the variable state. Test this example code, and you will find the issue where data doesn't change on type3(variable) case.

```dart
class Test3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test3> createState() => _Test3State();
}

class _Test3State extends State<Test3> {
  String data = "A";
  late Widget _myDisplay = Text("$data");
  Widget _myDisplayMethod() => Text("$data");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          data = "b";
        });
      }),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _myDisplay, //variables doesn't update state(based on cases)
            _myDisplayMethod(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can I say then that using variables is better if I intentionally want the displayed widgets to not be updated?

Comment: think so, on if it is independent , more like final

Comment: It breaks the context chain, which means you're violating the build system's contract.  If it works, it's accidental, and have fun debugging if it doesn't work.  The framework already works very hard to not rebuild widgets.  It's very unlikely that you can do a better job by hand.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz hm so you’d actually recommend that I avoid using variables to hold widgets?

Comment: Correct.  Widgets should arise only during the build() chain.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz hmm… how about lists of widgets, like used in columns or rows? If I want a dynamically changing list, I inevitably have to update the list in some method outside of the build() chain right? How does that compare to using a Widget stored in a variable?

Comment: you update the List of data that the widgets depend on.