# list view not refreshing in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-state

I am using two bottomnavigationbar item where two tabs for alltodos and completedtodos

here  as a demo purpose I have placed a refresh button on AppBar to load data and used setState to rebuild but it does not rebuild list view , therefor to see data, I have to click on bottom tab..

I want auto refresh on clicking refresh button

here is my code...

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int selectedindex=0;

  final tabs=[
    ViewList(iscompleted: false,),
    ViewList(iscompleted:true),
  ];



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Main Build Method');

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Todo App'),
        actions: [IconButton(onPressed: (){
          alltodos.clear();
           alltodos.add(Todo(title: 'first',iscompleted: false));
          alltodos.add(Todo(title: 'Second',iscompleted: false));
          alltodos.add(Todo(title: 'Third',iscompleted: false));
          alltodos.add(Todo(title: 'Fourth',iscompleted: true));
          alltodos.add(Todo(title: 'Fifith',iscompleted: false));
          alltodos.add(Todo(title: 'Sixth',iscompleted: false));
          alltodos.add(Todo(title: 'Seven',iscompleted: true));
          setState(() {
          });
        }, icon: Icon(Icons.refresh))],),
        body:tabs[selectedindex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
          currentIndex: selectedindex,
          onTap: (index){
            selectedindex=index;
            setState(() {
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.fact_check_outlined),
                label: 'Todos'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Completed',
                icon: Icon(Icons.done))
          ],
        ),


    );
  }

}


class ViewList extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool iscompleted;

  ViewList({required this.iscompleted});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Todo> mylist=alltodos.where((element) {
      return element.iscompleted==iscompleted;
    }).toList();

   return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: mylist.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
        final todo=mylist[index];
        return ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(),
          title: Text(todo.title),
          subtitle: Text(todo.iscompleted.toString()),

        );

        });
  }
}
```

todo model class

```
class Todo
{

  String title;
  bool iscompleted;

  Todo({required this.title,this.iscompleted=false});



}

List<Todo> alltodos=[
 
];
```

Comment: Awaiting solution.....

Comment: Are you using gobal variable for `alltodos`

Comment: Yes in a separate file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are creating variable, therefore it is breaking context update relation.

```dart
  final tabs=[
    ViewList(iscompleted: false,),
    ViewList(iscompleted:true),
  ];
```

You can reassign data by removing the final and this will update

```dart
onPressed: () {
  ..
  tabs = [
    ViewList(
      iscompleted: false,
    ),
    ViewList(iscompleted: true),
  ];
  setState(() {});
},
```

Better, When you need something that will rebuild, use helper method or widget

```dart
tabs() => [
        ViewList(
          iscompleted: false,
        ),
        ViewList(iscompleted: true),
      ];
```

And use

```dart
body: tabs()[selectedindex],
```

Also it will be a good startup using state-management like provider/riverpod/bloc

Comment: same, I have already done with provider successfully...but suddenly I thought it can be done without provider as looks simple , and really could not figure out what was wrong...Now still confused but will study your code..Thanks a lot for ur great help..

Comment: The wrong part is using variable  on state class. Like once, you assign a value it doesn't update itself, you need to assign again.

Comment: You mean to my this state variable.    List<Todo> mylist=alltodos.where((element) {
      return element.iscompleted==iscompleted;
    }).toList();

Comment: nope `final tabs=[`

Comment: sorry..I mean to the same final tabs...by mistake I copied List<todo>...Okay got it now

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73005068/10157127) including comments

Answer (score 1):

you must call setState every time you change the state.

```
setState(() { myList.add('text'); });
```