# ListView.builder build new elements using Bloc?

Tags: flutter, listview, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm using `GroupedListView` (which is based on `ListView.builder`) to implement a chat.

I have a `ChatBloc` bloc that is responsible to handle new messages from the DataLayer. Whenever new messages are added, I'm emitting a new state of elements, **and rebuild the whole ListView**.

Here is my code:

```
child: BlocBuilder<ChatBloc, ChatState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    final userId = context.read<AppBloc>().state.user.userId;
    return GroupedListView<Message, DateTime>(
    controller: scrollController,
    elements: state.messages,
    reverse: true,
    cacheExtent: 9999,
    order: GroupedListOrder.DESC,
    itemComparator: (element1, element2) =>
      element1.timestamp.compareTo(element2.timestamp),
    itemBuilder: (context, element) =>
      element.messageToWidget(userId, state.senders),
    groupBy: (element) => DateTime(
      element.timestamp.year,
      element.timestamp.month,
      element.timestamp.day,
    ),
    groupHeaderBuilder: (element) => Center(
    child: TitleMessage(
    text: dateFormat03.format(element.timestamp),
    ),
   ),
  );
 },
)
```

The problem is that **I don't want to rebuild everything again** with every new message that is added to the list.

**I want to build new messages only.**

How do I do that using Bloc state management?

## Update

According to `@Harsimran Singh` `ListView.builder` does not recycle its elements on refresh (even due adding a unique Key to each element).

Using `ListView.custom` with `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` seems not to solve the issue:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
return ListView.custom(
    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
      (context, index) {
        final message = state.messages.elementAt(index);
        return message.messageToWidget(
          userId: userId,
          senders: state.senders,
          key: Key(message.toString()),
        );
      },
      childCount: state.messages.length,
      findChildIndexCallback: (key) {
        return state.messages
            .indexWhere((e) => Key(e.toString()) == key);
      },
    ),
  );
```

I debugged the code and the `findChildIndexCallback` works just fine and returns the correct index. But according to the above video, you can see that the elements are still rendered.

Why is that?

Comment: I'd use a copy with state for the bloc, add you bloc snippet here. Include the state.

Comment: I'm using copyWith, but that's not the issue. My problem is that whenever a new state emits from my ChatBloc, with an updated list of elements, my ListView.builder builds everything again, instead of building the new messages only.

Comment: You're probably not emitting a new state on new data instead of copying old state.

Comment: Why do you think that? here is the emit code  emit(
      state.copyWith(
        status: ChatStatus.success,
        messages: messages,
        senders: senders,
      ),
    );

Comment: I don't think there is away to get this behaviour with bloc but it's possible with riverpod.

Comment: How does it work with riverpod? what's the difference?

Comment: `cacheExtent:9999` means you want to build `9999` pixels before of showing item and `9999` pixels after of showing item. more info at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/cacheExtent.html

Comment: I think you supposed to reduce `cacheExtent` to (normal mobile height  ~ 2778 ) for example  `cacheExtent : 2778`

Comment: How does it relate to this discussion?

Comment: @genericUser listView.builder by default would build necessary items if you set right `cacheExtent`. when you add a message to list you have to build the list again and listview.builder would decide to build which items again. Then flutter engine will decide which items are `dirty` and need to rebuild and can't reuse.

Comment: so to improve performance of your list I suggest to `reduce cacheExtent ` and use `const` keyword for your Message Shower widget . `const` keyword prevent rebuild a widget if it exist in widget tree. more info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492705/does-using-const-in-the-widget-tree-improve-performance

Comment: Yes but the question is not about how to build my widgets faster, it's about how not to rebuild them at first.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is not related to bloc at all. In fact
`ListView.builder` will always rebuild all of its children, independently
to setting a key for them.

The solution I found is to use a `ListView.custom` with a
`SliverChildBuilderDelegate`. Then assign a key to its children and
retrieving the key from the index works as expected and the child is not
rebuilt.

**Note that** `childCount` and `findChildIndexCallback` are parameters
of the sliver and not the list itself.

Here is an example:

```
ListView.custom(
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return MessageWidget(
                        key: ValueKey('m-${state.messages[index].messageId}'
                           ),
                        message: state.messages[index],
                      );
              },
              childCount: state.messages.length,
              findChildIndexCallback: (key) {
                final ValueKey<String> valueKey = key as ValueKey<String>;
                final index = state.messages
                    .indexWhere((m) => 'm-${m.messageId}' == valueKey.value);
                return index;
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Didn't try it yet but it sounds good. Why it doesn't work using ListView.builder with key for each element? What is the difference?

Comment: Regardless of key listview.builder will rebuild the childeran. When a child is scrolled out of view, the associated element subtree, states and render objects are destroyed. A new child at the same position in the list will be lazily recreated along with new elements, states and render objects when it is scrolled back.

Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html (Child elements' lifecycle)

Comment: Hey @Harsimran Singh thanks for your reply. `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` seems not to solve my issue. I think you are at the right path, but it seems that my elements are still rendering. I updated my question based on your answer and added a gif that show the problem is still exists.

Comment: Can you please give a message ID instead of a message as a key? 
The reason that is happening is due to your key.

Comment: The comparing is working just fine. Each message has different unique fields, and I'm using `Equatable` with all fields to compare them. I debug each time my messages render, and the returned index from `findChildIndexCallback` was correct. I also tried using `message.id` or `message.timestamp` (since it's unique) for comparing but it didn't help. Can you please provide a simple example that works? Try to debug it and check if its elements are still rendering on each refresh. Thank you for your help. Appriciate

Comment: please check if both `message.timestamp` and `message.id` are the same as before and after `setState()`.

If the key is different then it will rerender the children.

Comment: Messages fields are independent of `setState` refreshing. I also mentioned that the findChildIndexCallback works just fine and returns the right index. Which means the Key does not change and the compering works as expected.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with working `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` that does not render its children on every `setState`? I think it will help me to understand what I did wrong.

Comment: @genericUser I tested your code on my device and it works fine there may be any other issue. can you share anything outside the list view? that may help to debug

Comment: Hello @genericUser if you are still stuck please let me know else please accept the answer :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to your blocStream in initState and use animated list instead of your current list so you can insert items in real-time

It can be done by defining a global key like this:

```
final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> messagesKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
```

and then insert the value like:

```
messagesList.add(NEW_MESSAGE);
messagesKey.currentState?.insertItem(messagesList.length - 1);
```

and if you want to remove an item with animations you can:

```
  messagesKey.currentState?.removeItem(
  index,
  (context, animation) => buildMessage(index, animation),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define and use chat object like this "context.read().state.user.userId;" instead when using from state. It will update only the widget not the build method.

Comment: `read()` works only once. In this case, since I want to listen for changes and refresh the widget, `select()` should be the right function. But it's irrelevant since BlocBuilder works the same as `select()`. My issue is about the problem of building the whole ListView again after adding an element to the list. That's my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Don't wrap your ListView with a bloc builder in that case, use BlocListener

```
BlocListener<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    setState((){
       // Have a copy of messages in your widget and update it as you wish (implement getNewMessages)
       messages = getNewMessages(state.messages)
    })
  },
  child: ListView.builder(
     elements: messages
  ),
)
```

Comment: It won't do nothing... setState case a rebuild of the whole stateful widget

Comment: You cannot change the parameters of a widget without setting state.  If that doesn't solve your problem then nothing will.

Comment: You should read more about BlocBuilder. read the official documentation https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocbuilder

Comment: Emitting events is the same as setting state, no need to read any documentation, as long as you're using ListView, you cannot update the contents without changing state

Comment: I updated the state, and it was emitted successfully. So your answer is irrelevant, because BlocBuilder does the same as setState with Lister

Comment: You should read my whole question again. I think u read only the title.