# Const keyword performance improvement in reference to Text Theme

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When I am using Text widget, there are two ways from which I can change style of widget

1. Passing `TextStyle` to style permeter.
2. Passing `Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge` to style permeter.

when using first method I can use const keyword in front of Text widget and in second cannot.
does using first method give me performance boost ?

I know using second method my code will be more organised.
Which method should I use ?

```
Text("Select a City",style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,),

const Text("Select a City",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color:Colors.grey)),
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. **const** makes that widget not to be rebuild when you call setState or otherwise, it can help you increase performance.
2. You should use method 2 because it synchronizes your application, making it easy to change the theme mode

Comment: Does this helps [How to add link or code in comment area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492705/does-using-const-in-the-widget-tree-improve-performance)